# Dynamic video tag change not working in ie9

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

There are lot of answers available on net / stackoverflow, I have tried all of them but none of them working as i wanted.

My scenaraio is like this:

A visual webpart having a repeater control containing a list of videos, with a play link, upon clicking which i want to change video dynamically.

here is the ascx page code:

```
    <div id="divVideo">
            <video id="videoPlayer" width="320" height="240" controls>
              <source id="mp4Source" src="/_layouts/1033/Styles/PlayVideo/testVid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
<ul>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrVideoCase" OnItemDataBound="rptrVideoCase_ItemDataBound">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <li><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTitle" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /> <a class="playLink" style="float:right; cursor:pointer;">Play Video</a><asp:HiddenField
                               ID="hfVideoURL" runat="server" />
                       </li>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ul>
```

In javascript:

Approach #1(Adding video tag without reloading page)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".playLink").on("click", function () {

    var videoSource = $(this).next().val();
    var htmlVideo = "<video width='320' height='240' src = '" + videoSource + "' type='video/mp4' controls>"
        $("#divVideo").html("");
        $("#divVideo").html(htmlVideo);
});
});
```

Approach #2(Doing a page refresh with querystring parameter)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var videoSourcefrmQryString = getUrlVars()["videoSource"];

    $(".playLink").on("click", function () {

    window.location.href = window.location + "?videoSource=" + videoSource;
    });

    if (videoSourcefrmQryString.length > 0) {
            var htmlVideo = "<video width='320' height='240' src = '" + videoSourcefrmQryString + "' type='video/mp4' controls>"
            $("#divVideo").html("");
            $("#divVideo").html(htmlVideo);
        }

        function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
        }
});
```

Both the approaches are working fine in FF and chrome but in IE 9, when the page loads for first time the video plays(This was also not working previously after adding a .htaccess file with mime types it worked)
but upon clicking the links the player shows a red cross at the center, which is simillar to the case when there is no .htaccess file.
By using network capture in IE Developer tool i can see upon first load the content type of video comes as "video/mp4", but upon clicking the play link the content type changes.
Quick guess is upon clicking the link the mime types are not loading(not sure though!).

Are there any resolution to this scenario? Please Suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the cause, There are some file handling restriction when it comes to sharepoint 2010.Some settings needs to be changed in sharepoint central admin and iis.

Thee link [here](http://gavinb.net/2011/07/19/serving-html5-video-from-sharepoint-document-libraries/) mentioned the steps in detail.

And also we need not have to add .htaccess file for this.
With the changes mentioned in the link above and using the Approach #1 mentioned in question did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try change only the `src` attrib: `var videoEl = $("#mp4Source");videoEl.attr("src", videoSourceValue); videoEl.get(0).play();`

Comment: Changing only the src attribute will not work, either you have to replace the whole source tag or you have to replace whole video tag

Comment: Could you provide what is generated HTML before and after the click?

Comment: Have you tried javascript function `play` `video.play()` after changing the src attr? I updated the answer

Comment: Yeah i have tried, that time it was not working. And as I mentioned now I got the cause which is sharepoint blocking the normal behavior of file handling, hence the content type of video was not getting reflected properly. I haven't tried after that, as with my approach it is working fine. Do you want me to check with this approach now and update the same?